# Renaming gcov files for various compilation

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gcov

how can i give particular name to .gcda and .gcno files each time compile rather than the default name so that i can combine all results in lcov.

Suppose in following code.

```
enter code here
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter an integer\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    if ( n%2 == 0 )
       printf("Even\n");
    else
       printf("Odd\n");

    return 0;
}
```

On compiling first time i want to generate test1.gcno and test1.gcda file and on again i want to generate test2.gcno and test.2gcda files if the name of the c file is saved as check.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Windows, you can use `CopyFile(source, destination, FALSE);`
Checking the number of times you've compiled, just analyze how many files were copied by by `CopyFile()` with an open file function like `fopen("test.txt", "r");`. It return NULL if the file does not exist.